# Google Maps URL prevent waypoint reorder

Tags: google-maps

**Question:**
There are some answers on stackoverflow about building a google maps url to open and display a route in a browser. The parameters are explained [here](http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters) for example.

Now i have following case. My start and destination address are the same and between are some waypoints. The route is traveled by car. The URL looks like:

[https://www.google.ch/maps?saddr=Bern&daddr=Bern+to:Paris+to:Berlin+to:Rome+to:&dirflg=d](https://www.google.ch/maps?saddr=Bern&daddr=Bern%20to:Paris%20to:Berlin%20to:Rome%20to:&dirflg=d)

If you click these link you will see that google reorders the points of the whole route. First start, then end point and then all the waypoints. Instead of start -> waypoints -> end. This reordering happens because (and only when) the start and destination addresses are the same.

Does anybody know a way (or parameter) to prevent this reordering? Thanks ;)

**A possible solution or a modified question:**
If there would be another (officially documented) way to build a URL the problem could be solved. If you click above link and drag the second Bern (end address) manually to the end and execute the request, then you see a new URL in following format:

https://www.google.ch/maps/dir/Bern/Paris,+Frankreich/Berlin,+Deutschland/Rom,+Italien/Bern (... cut data= etc.)

This URL would be the answer to my question, but i do not know how i could influence for example the travel mode (car, walking, transit, bicycle). Is this URL format documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the example of geocodezip i realized the mistake i made in the url.

Following does not work:
[https://www.google.ch/maps?saddr=Bern&daddr=Bern+to:Paris+to:Berlin+to:Rome&dirflg=d](https://www.google.ch/maps?saddr=Bern&daddr=Bern%20to:Paris%20to:Berlin%20to:Rome&dirflg=d)

Following works:
[https://www.google.ch/maps?saddr=Bern&daddr=Paris+to:Berlin+to:Rome+to:Bern&dirflg=d](https://www.google.ch/maps?saddr=Bern&daddr=Paris%20to:Berlin%20to:Rome%20to:Bern&dirflg=d)

I misinterpreted saddr = source address, daddr = destination address and the +to as waypoints. But in fact the daddr has to be the second point in the route. And the end of the route is the last +to part.

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters are for the "old" google maps.  The new google maps is different.  There are documented APIs for creating embedded maps now:

[Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode)

The following URL parameters are required:

- origin defines the starting point from which to display directions. The value can be either a place name or address. The string should be URL-escaped, so an address such as "City Hall, New York, NY" should be converted to City+Hall,New+York,NY. (The Google Maps Embed API supports both + and %20 when escaping spaces.)
- destination defines the end point of the directions.

The following URL parameters are optional:

- waypoints specifies one or more intermediary places to route directions through between the origin and destination. Multiple waypoints can be specified by using the pipe character (|) to separate places (e.g. Berlin,Germany|Paris,France). You can specify up to 20 waypoints.
- mode defines the method of travel. Options are driving, walking (which prefers pedestrian paths and sidewalks, where available), bicycling (which routes via bike paths and preferred streets where available), transit, or flying. If no mode is specified, the Embed API will show one or more of the most relevant modes for the specified route.
- avoid tells Google Maps to avoid tolls, ferries and/or highways. Separate multiple values with the pipe character (e.g. avoid=tolls|highways). Note that this doesn't preclude routes that include the restricted feature(s); it simply biases the result to more favorable routes.
- units specifies either metric or imperial units when displaying distances in the results. If units are not specified, the origin country of the query determines the units to use.

[Your example using the Embed API](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map.html)

Comment: I am already able to embed a map using the Google Maps JavaScript API V3. I really want to build an URL because only that allows to open a route in a browser allowing the user to manipulate the route using the current standard google maps user interface in full screen which he knows. Embedding a map is in my opinion ok when you are just viewing the route. But your example showed me the mistake i made :)! The link behind "More options" in your examples shows the url which works. It looks like this embed API uses the old format.